# Como obter a identidade de um objeto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Diversas linguagens possuem um meio de se obter a "identidade" de um objeto, i.e. um número [inteiro] que é único para cada objeto, tal que objetos diferentes tenham identidades diferentes. Exemplos:

- Java ([`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29))

> Tanto quanto razoavelmente prático, o método hashCode definido pela classe Object retorna inteiros distintos para objetos distintos. (Isto é tipicamente implementado convertendo o endereço interno do objeto em um inteiro, mas essa técnica de implementação não é exigida pela linguagem de programação Java.)

- Python ([`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id))

> Retorna a "identidade" de um objeto. Isto é um inteiro (ou inteiro longo) que é garantido ser único e constante para esse objeto durante seu ciclo de vida. Dois objetos com tempo de vida não sobrepostos podem ter o mesmo valor para id().

Existe alguma funcionalidade semelhante em JavaScript? De preferência padronizada, que funcionasse em todos os browsers e outros ambientes (Rhino, V8). Buscando por "identity" eu somente encontro referências para o operador (`===`)...

Sei que alguns ambientes não suportam esse conceito (.NET aparentemente [não o faz por razões de otimização](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750958/520779)), mas em geral isso não é problema pois são linguagens mais completas, que possuem os conceitos de **destrutor**, **finalizador** e/ou **referências fracas**. Até onde eu saiba, JavaScript não suporta isso, de modo que uma maneira de se obter um valor numérico que unicamente representa um objeto seria muito útil (uma simples referência pro objeto não serve, pois ela o impediria de ser coletado como lixo).

Comment: Você pode exemplificar em que cenário esse id seria usado? Por que você guardaria o id de um objeto que já foi coletado como lixo?

Comment: @rodrigorgs Justamente para saber **quando** e **se** ele foi coletado como lixo. Como JavaScript [[ainda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6774185/520779)] não dá suporte a referências fracas, e [não parece haver nenhum *workaround* satisfatório](http://stackoverflow.com/q/266704/520779), minha única saída é tentar "simulá-las" através de uma referência indireta (ainda estou trabalhando nos detalhes). Para casos de uso para referências fracas, tem um material interessante [aqui](http://www.maxwell.lambda.ele.puc-rio.br/10985/10985_4.PDF) (Aviso: PDF).

Comment: A linguagem não prevê nenhuma maneira de se obter esse tipo de identidade, portanto se algum interpretador inclui isso, é de maneira não padronizada.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A especificação [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) não prevê essa funcionalidade na linguagem, e não tenho conhecimento de nenhum motor de JavaScript que implemente isso.

Se quiser implementar você mesmo, um ponto de partida é isto (baseado nesta [resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997661/unique-object-identifier-in-javascript)):

```
(function(){
    var id = 0;
    Object.prototype.getIdentity = function() {
        if(!this.hasOwnProperty('__identity__')) {
            this.__identity__ = ++id;
        }
        return this.__identity__;
    };
}());
```

Note que `__identity__` é uma propriedade pública que todos os objetos que invocaram `getIdentity` uma vez passam a ter. Portanto nada impede que ela seja manipulada diretamente, o que potencialmente comprometeria os resultados.

Uma implementação com recursos do ECMAScript 5 (ou seja, incompatível com motores antigos como o do IE8) consegue impedir isso:

```
(function(){
    var id = 0;
    Object.prototype.getIdentity = function() {
        if(!this.hasOwnProperty('__identity__')) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, '__identity__', { 
                enumerable: false,
                writable: false,
                value: ++id 
            });
        }
        return this.__identity__;
    };
}());
```

O atributo `writable: false` garante que o valor de `__identity__` não possa ser alterado manualmente. E `enumerable: false` omite a propriedade de enumerações `for..in`, ou serialização via `JSON.stringify`, conforme a sugestão do talles.

Comment: Creio que tem razão. Já havia dado uma olhada nas especificações (tanto da versão corrente quanto do último rascunho da versão 6) e também não encontrei nada, mas tinha a esperança de que houvesse alguma funcionalidade obscura da qual não tivesse conhecimento.

Comment: Na versão 5.1 te garanto que não tem. Na 6 eu duvido, mas não boto a mão no fogo...

Comment: Sugiro trocar `this.__identity__ = ++id` por `Object.defineProperty(this, '__identity__', { enumerable: false, value: ++id })`. Desta maneira a propriedade `__identity__` não irá aparecer em loops *for..in* ou em uma chamada a *JSON.stringify*.

Comment: Obrigado, @talles. Acrescentei sua sugestão mas mantive a versão original, já que ela funciona em implementações pré-ES5. Com `Object.defineProperty` também dá para impedir que `__identity__` seja alterada manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se adicionar uma funcionalidade global para o tipo `String`:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var character = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + character;
        hash = hash & hash; // Converte para inteiro 32 bit
    }
    return hash;
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076436/1653643)

A biblioteca [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com) oferece algumas funcionalidades úteis. Uma delas é a possibilidade de comparar a equivalência de dois valores

http://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

```
var object = { 'name': 'fred' };
var copy = { 'name': 'fred' };

object == copy;
// → false

_.isEqual(object, copy);
// → true

var words = ['hello', 'goodbye'];
var otherWords = ['hi', 'goodbye'];

_.isEqual(words, otherWords, function(a, b) {
  var reGreet = /^(?:hello|hi)$/i,
      aGreet = _.isString(a) &amp;&amp; reGreet.test(a),
      bGreet = _.isString(b) &amp;&amp; reGreet.test(b);

  return (aGreet || bGreet) ? (aGreet == bGreet) : undefined;
});
// → true
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente o que estou buscando é o **contrário** do que você propõe: um valor que seja único para o objeto, de modo que ainda que dois objetos sejam idênticos [porém distintos] eles ainda possuam uma identidade diferente. Em outras palavras, `id(x) == id(y)` se e somente se `x === y`.

Comment: Entendi. Acredito que as únicas maneiras em JavaScript, ou seja manter uma hashtable cada vez que um objeto é criado, ou transformar a função `toString` para retornar um identificador único do objeto com uma variável global `id` sendo incrementada a cada criação.