# O que seria a "identidade" de um objeto?

Tags: variáveis, terminologia, objetos

Lendo mais sobre **objetos**, tentando me "desprender" do conceito de que objeto seria apenas provido de uma "classe", [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205491/92908), vi a seguinte frase:

> "Objetos possuem identidade. Uma variável não."

O que seria a identidade de um objeto? Por que variáveis não possuem uma?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL; DR

É a forma de determinar o que é o objeto e em alguns casos distinguir um objeto do outro. Onde mais é usado é determinar se é o mesmo objeto ou outro. É como você sabe quem é o João e quem é o José, ou é o João da Silva, ou é o João da Silva com a filiação tal (por isso que certas características sozinhas não podem ser usadas para criar identidade única).

## Introdução

Esse é um termo controverso. Não vou dizer que boa parte das pessoas usam o termo de forma errada, como o fiz em [outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) (lá eu consegui fundamentar a diferença melhor, por isso lá falo que está errado, aqui não).

Há uma definição do que é identidade de objeto no contexto de orientação a objeto. Não gosto dela, porque ela se apropria do termo que pode ser aplicado de outra forma universalmente e diferentemente e dá outro significado. Não é segredo que eu [considero OOP algo bem mal definido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) e conceitualmente tem menos valor que outras disciplinas, até porque o que dá certo quase sempre já vem de outras disciplinas.

Eu pegarei a definição que considero mais universal e ela vem [da wiki raiz](https://wiki.c2.com/?ObjectIdentity) onde tem bons profissionais tentando criar conhecimento de qualidade sobre computação, e costumam conseguir, e não vou pegar [da wiki nutella](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/402/101) onde algumas pessoas ajudam criar algum conhecimento geral, e nem sempre dá certo.

Então aconselho ler ambos para entender cada contexto. Todo conhecimento é bem vindo, até quando causa confusão :) Aprenda discernir o joio do trigo.

Se quer ater-se apenas à definição de OOP pode não gostar da resposta, mas eu acho que a pergunta não era sobre isso, a origem dela foi em pergunta sobre a definição universal de objeto, não a usada em OOP. Se for identidade em DDD então, aí piorou :)

## Identidade única X equivalente

Uma das coisas que que eu não concordo muito é o próprio termo identidade. Porque ele é usado querendo dizer que é uma identidade única, e por isso o termo deveria ser esse, composto. Se usar só o termo "identidade" eu acho que pode ser outra coisa. Mas tem definição que diz que identidade é única. Isso parece confuso, vou dar minha versão. Não afirmo que ela está correta, faça seu julgamento. Se discorda então fique só com a identidade única.

Existe a identidade única e a identidade equivalente. Pra mim todo objeto tem uma identidade, seja a primeira ou a segunda, não faz sentido não ter, não sei nem como chamar um objeto sem identidade.

A **identidade única**, que as pessoas chamam só de identidade, é fácil entender. Você tem alguma identificação no objeto que o torna único. Se você tiver objetos com essa característica igual (idêntica) no fundo eles são o mesmo objeto (ou entidade em certo contexto). Pode ser um endereço de memória que determina isso (a tal da [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)), pode ser um `id` garantidamente único (UUID por exemplo, mas pode ser algo sequencial), pode até ser um nome, desde que único em toda solução, ou um conjunto de características que juntas se tornam única, pode ser até mesmo todo o objeto, e é mais comum do que se imagina, principalmente em objetos imutáveis.

A **identidade equivalente** é quando o objeto possui uma identidade não distinta, ou seja, você pode ter dois objetos completamente diferentes e você não consegue dizer quem é quem. O melhor exemplo é um número 1 em um objeto numérico. Você pode ter dois objetos com esse valor que nada tem a ver um com o outro, é só uma coincidência que eles são o mesmo valor, e não tem informação adicional alguma que os distingua. Pra mim eles possuem identidade (é o número 1) e ela é equivalente nos dois objetos. Para outras pessoas eles não possuem identidade (onde eu não concordo).

Por isso objetos por referência possuem uma identidade natural se nenhuma outra forma existir para distinguir os objetos (em vários casos outras existem e são melhores). Se você tem a mesma referência em dois lugares diferentes certamente elas estão apontando para o mesmo objeto.

Na segunda definição da C2 wiki (tirando a introdução) o autor entende que só importa a identidade equivalente, mas pode ser o contexto que ele usou.

Se continuar lendo lá tem outras formas de definir o que é a identidade. Eu acho isso bom, ainda que cause confusão. Não temos uma definição definitiva clara (a não ser que alguém me mostre uma).

## Identidade interna X externa

A identidade interna ou lógica independe do contexto onde o objeto está sendo usado, e ele depende dos seus valores. É comum só algumas partes do objeto serem consideradas para dar uma identidade única. Exemplos: um `id` de uma pessoa, o CNPJ de uma empresa (isso pode ser um pouco polêmico, veja [Valores que podem ser inseridos como chave primária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101)).

Já a identidade externa ou física depende do contexto e de onde o objeto está. É o caso da referência dita acima, então se duplicar esse objeto passa ter dois objetos diferentes, ou seja, pode ter dois "joãos" idênticos (tudo mesmo, ser a mesma pessoa), o que em geral é problemático (algumas metodologias "modernas" pregam isso e tem causado vários problemas), é algo que deve ser evitado, pra isso existe a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Então tem que tomar cuidado com identidades externas porque entre uma execução e outra pode mudar, e ser a mesma entidade. Para a maioria dos efeitos a identidade interna é que importa pra gente.

A identidade interna acaba permitindo até que dois objetos diferentes sejam a mesma entidade. Eu não gosto disso, cria problemas, mas muita gente faz. Por exemplo pode ter um cliente e um fornecedor que são objetos distintos mas eles são a mesma entidade, são a mesma empresa, tem uma informação única que está presente nos dois objetos, um `id` por exemplo, ou o CNPJ, se quiser arriscar. Pra mim sistema que faz isso quer confusão, e falo disso em várias respostas aqui no site.

## Mutabilidade

Objetos mutáveis podem ter várias características que podem ser mudadas e a identidade do objeto não muda, por exemplo a idade, ou mesmo o nome. Outras características não podem mudar. Mudar uma característica específica mudará a identidade, e algumas pessoas não percebem quais são elas. Por exemplo a pessoa pode achar que se mudar o CPF muda a identidade, mas não muda, é possível trocar de CPF por várias razões e ser a mesma pessoa, portanto deve ser o mesmo objeto.

Objetos imutáveis não podem mudar característica alguma sem mudar a identidade, ainda que a nova identidade seja equivalente à antiga. Então pra mim quando você faz

```
x = 1
x = 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Identity.ptg).

a segunda linha, conceitualmente, está criando um novo objeto com sua identidade, e está atribuindo para uma variável que já tinha um objeto com uma identidade, e nesse caso as identidades dos objetos são equivalentes.

A variável não importa nada disso de identidade, ela não tem. O máximo que poderíamos dizer é que ela é identificada pelo seu nome, mas isso é outra coisa completamente diferente, há uma identificação, mas não é o mesmo conceito.

Entenda mais em [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

## Variáveis X objetos

Minha intenção naquela resposta foi diferenciar uma coisa da outra. Como [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um local de armazenamento não tem porque ela ter identidade, o conteúdo dela muda, e se muda a identidade muda, então a variável não pode ter identidade própria, o que está nela é que tem, é só isso.

#### Outro nível de abstração

Correndo o risco de causar mais confusão, podemos até dizer que a variável tem identidade, ma em outro nível de abstração. Considere isso uma explicação completamente isolada do resto da resposta.

Entenda aqui que o código não deixa de ser uma base de dados. São textos que relacionados tem algum significado. O código nesse contexto é algo que existe por si só e não se confunde com a aplicação que você está criando, nada a ver com o executável que rodará sua aplicação.

Se considerar que variável é um objeto do código (não confundir com objeto da aplicação) então ele tem identidade, porque todo objeto tem identidade. Essa identidade é dada por atributos (já *linkei* pergunta sobre o assunto logo no começo). Ela tem nome, ela costuma ter tipo (em linguagens de [tipagem estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101)), escopo, pelo menos área de armazenamento, e talvez outras características. Depende da linguagem e contexto, mas mudando apenas uma delas já é outra variável.

Então não é que estou dizendo que variável tem identidade, mas que nesse nível de abstração que estamos olhando a variável é um objeto e todo objeto tem identidade.

Se não consegue entender a diferença do que é sua aplicação e o que é sua base de código, esqueça essa parte por um tempo.

## Extra

Pesquisando sobre, achei uma [pergunta aqui que mostra como muita gente não entende bem o que é a identidade do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/402/101), e não estou falando de ninguém ali na página, estou falando do criador da API do Java. Ele acha que um *hashcode* pode demonstrar a identidade de um objeto. *Hashcodes* podem se repetir, podem se confundir com outras coisas. Se pelo menos fosse o tipo mais o *hashcode* ajudaria um pouco, mas ainda pode se repetir.

Answer (score 2):

Então, vou ser bem breve e resumir.

### Tanto Objeto quanto Variável tem identidades.

> **O que é um identificador ?**

Cada variável possui um identificador, **que é um nome dado a ela** e assim, toda vez que precisarmos usá-la, basta declarar o seu identificador.

> **O que seria a identidade de um objeto?**

Um objeto é a representação de um conceito/entidade do mundo real, que pode ser física (bola, carro, árvore, etc.) ou conceitual (viagem, estoque, compra, etc) e possui um significado bem definido para um determinado software. Para esse conceito/entidade, deve ser definida inicialmente uma classe a partir da qual posteriormente serão instanciados objetos distintos.

> **Por que variáveis não possuem uma?**

As variáveis são elementos básicos na programação, pois são aquelas que armazenam os dados que precisamos no nosso algoritmo. Cada dado pode ser de um tipo diferente e, por isso precisamos mostrar ao nosso algoritmo logo no início o que esperar armazenar.

Imagine, por exemplo, que precisamos separar roupas do vestuário de acordo com o seu tipo dentro de um armário. Esse é quem arruma a bagunça, por isso o consideramos nosso algoritmo, como vemos na **Figura 1**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Figura 1.** Como guardamos dados

Entendemos com a **Figura 1** que cada gaveta corresponde a uma variável, que é um espaço dentro da memória do computador, ou seja, do nosso armário.

Na **Gaveta 1** guardamos roupas do tipo camisa, na **Gaveta 2** guardamos roupas do tipo calças e na **Gaveta 3** do tipo bermuda. Na **Gaveta 2** sabemos que não vamos encontrar camisas, pois esse é o tipo de roupa da **Gaveta 1**.